# Как в pandas применить метод rolling к нескольким столбцам DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Подскажите, как правильнее скользящим окном пройтись по датафрейму для нескольких столбцов? Окно например 3х3.

Я хочу вычислять максимум из значений попадающих в это окно и записать их в новый столбец. Вот мой код в несколько действий:

```
x = pd.Series([1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 6, 2, 8, 3, 0, 1, 2, 1, 5])

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": x**2+8, "B": x*8, "C": x+34})
df[['maxA','maxB','maxC']]  = df.loc[:,'A':'C'].rolling(3).max()
df['Max_ABC']  = df.loc[:,['maxA','maxB','maxC']].max(axis=1)

df
```

Сейчас я использую промежуточное вычисление как на рисунке, используя столбцы ['maxA','maxB','maxC'] только для получения промежуточного результата. Мне видится что это лишний шаг вычисления, и наверное есть более простой способ решения.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Знаете ли более пандовский метод для работы со скользящим окном, чтобы получить сразу нужный столбец как на рисунке ниже?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [46]: df['Max_ABC'] = df[['A','B','C']].rolling(3).max().max(axis='columns')

In [47]: df
Out[47]:
    A   B   C  Max_ABC
0   9   8  35      NaN
1  12  16  36      NaN
2  17  24  37     37.0
3  24  32  38     38.0
4  33  40  39     40.0
5  44  48  40     48.0
6  57  56  41     57.0
7  72  64  42     72.0
```

---

Пояснение:

`df[['A','B','C']].rolling(3).max()` - возвращает максимумы в скользящем окне для всех указанных столбцов:

```
In [51]: df[['A','B','C']].rolling(3).max()
Out[51]:
      A     B     C
0   NaN   NaN   NaN
1   NaN   NaN   NaN
2  17.0  24.0  37.0
3  24.0  32.0  38.0
4  33.0  40.0  39.0
5  44.0  48.0  40.0
6  57.0  56.0  41.0
7  72.0  64.0  42.0
```

далее мы выбираем максимум для каждой строки, указав `axis='columns'`:

```
In [52]: df[['A','B','C']].rolling(3).max().max(axis='columns')
Out[52]:
0     NaN
1     NaN
2    37.0
3    38.0
4    40.0
5    48.0
6    57.0
7    72.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: мне нужно получить максимум стразу из трех столбцов, ваше предложение дает возможность получить максисмум только по отдельным столбцам. 
Я привел не очень удачный датасет, попробуйте использовать этот: x = `pd.Series([1, 4, 3, 2, 1, 6, 2, 8, 3, 0, 1, 2, 1, 5])`

`df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A": x**2+8, "B": x*8, "C": x+34})`

Comment: Да. То что нужно. Вы можете прокомментировать вот этот хвост? Не понятно как он работает: `max().max(axis='columns')`

Comment: @Mavar, дополнил ответ пояснением...